# Converting a PSD to HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css, photoshop, psd

Recently I have considered using Photoshop to create website templates, and then convert them into HTML and CSS.

My query is, when working with a PSD you want to convert, what is the best course of action?

Should I craft the main structure first and then work on fine tuning or start at the top and vigorously make my way to the bottom?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what comes handy for you. For me: first if I have a dashboard which has all the colors and buttons, containers, etc (components) for the websites, than I made the css classes for them. My best friend in this is the Bootstrap , so I don't have to worrie about the responsivity. After that I look up, the main structure of the site design. From the biggest to the smallest. Sometimes I draw them on a paper and made some scetches. So when I'm about to code, I will know exactly what I have to do. It is my workflow, but what and how you wanna do it, is up to you.

Answer (score 1):

use dreamweaver software than make html webpage with css style in one folder than start to top header section than left section middle section than right section lastly footer create with css and attach with html page ona see offline output

Answer (score 0):

There is no best approach to this.

I generally make all the classes in a `CSS file` for all elements on the page as shown in the `PSD template`.

Then use that file in HTML, which can be fine tuned using more `CSS`, `JS`